# Error trying to install SSDT-BI on Windows 10 / SQL server 2014 / Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, ssdt-bi

I have recently installed SQL Server 2014 (Developer Edition) on my Windows 10 Pro machine x64. I already had Visual Studio 2013 (Community Edition) installed and have successfully added SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to that. I have however just hit a problem when trying to install SSDT-BI.

[I got SSDT-BI from this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

I get the initial start up splash screen

[image]

But after a fairly long wait I then get the following error

[image]

A time out waiting for .NET compiler csc.exe ??

On the face of it I thought maybe I have a corrupt .NET installation, however, I've downloaded and validated with .NET Framework Setup Verification Tool at
[Aaron Stebner's WebLog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) and all versions check out ok.

Anyone seeing this scenario or have experience of seeing the .NET timeout issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.